# How to get controller name in another class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am developing MVC application.

I want to pass controller to some other class for validation purpose. 
After passing the controller, I am unable to get the controller name in that class.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Location location)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Validations v = new Validations();

            boolean b;


            //passing controller in another class's method
           b = v.ValidProperty(location);


           if (ValidProperties == true)
             {
                 db.Locations.Add(location);
                 db.SaveChanges();
                 return RedirectToAction("Index");

             }

        }


    }
```

Getting controller in below method

```
 public void  ValidProperty(object Controller)
    {

    //Gives an error in below line
        string CtrName = (string)Controller.ToString;

     }
```

How to get the controller Name ?

Comment: _What error do you get?_

Comment: I will tell the error, but whether I have used the proper syntax ? Please check the 2nd code block, whether I did casting properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = v.ValidProperty(ControllerContext);
```

you may be wondering where am I initializing ControllerContext variable.
well you don't have to

```
     public void  ValidProperty(ControllerContext ControllerContext)
        {
           // do your logic here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `ControllerContext.RouteContext.GetRequiredString("controller")`

Comment: How to use ControllerContext  ?  I am using an isolated class. which library I will need to use ControllerContext    ?

Comment: pass controller name to your function. Use ControllerContext.RouteContext.GetRequiredString("controller") to get controller name in Controller Action and pass it in ValidProperty. By the way, it seems that you doing wrong if validation depends on controller name

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the controller, you can just use

`RouteData.Values["controller"]`